# Change dropdown list item based on another cells value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm trying to figure out a way where if the two cells match in numbers, the dropdown list item changes to "stopp".

See the example here: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGiBa.png)

What I want it to do is when the column G has the same number as the column H, it changes the status to "Stopp".

Could someone help?

Comment: Can you share a minimum reproducible sample? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I believe you might need a ```forEach()``` loop to help check every row if G = H ```setValue("Stopp")``` https://spreadsheet.dev/foreach-loop-in-apps-script

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible to do directly in Google Sheets, you would need to incorporate some [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) to extend Google Sheets.

With Apps Script, you could simply create a function to check and update the values, or you could do it automatically with [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). Specifically, the most useful trigger in this situation would be the `onEdit()` trigger (you can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)), since it would run automatically every time that the document is edited.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var column1Index = 7; //LETTER G
  var column2Index = 8; //LETTER H
  var outputColumnIndex = 9; //LETTER I

  var numberOfRowsToCheck = 10;

  var column1Values = sheet.getRange(1,column1Index,numberOfRowsToCheck,1).getValues();
  var column2Values = sheet.getRange(1,column2Index,numberOfRowsToCheck,1).getValues();

  for (var i=0;i<column1Values.length;i++){
    if(column1Values[i][0] == column2Values[i][0]){
      sheet.getRange(i+1, outputColumnIndex).setValue("Stop");
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Well done, except it makes sense to add a couple conditions to prevent to run the code after changes within any cells on any sheets.

Comment: What happens if columns 7 and 8 are changing due to formula actions rather that user edits.  Those changes will not be caught.